# How to add collision for two collada objects in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection, collada

Am trying to add dae objects to a scene, and need to avoid overlapping objects in the scene. Right now I use boxes to create raycast from the box to see if it hits any other object. but would like to know if we can do the same without using boxes.

```
            mouse.set( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1 );

            raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

            var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

            if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

                var intersect = intersects[ 0 ];

                // delete cube

                if ( isShiftDown ) {

                    if ( intersect.object != plane ) {

                        scene.remove( intersect.object );

                        objects.splice( objects.indexOf( intersect.object ), 1 );

                    }

                // create cube

                } else {
                    var voxel = dae.clone();//new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeo, cubeMaterial );
                    voxel.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
                    voxel.position.divideScalar( 50 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 50 ).addScalar( 25 );

                    var bBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(dae);   
                    var cubeGeometry = new  THREE.BoxGeometry(bBox.size().x, bBox.size().y, bBox.size().z);//,1,1,1);
                    var wireMaterial2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x8888ff, opacity: 0.1, transparent: true, wireframe:true 
                     });    
                    var notHit = true;
                    //MovingCube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, wireMaterial2 );
                     //MovingCube.position.copy(voxel.position);

                    var wallGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( bBox.size().x/2, bBox.size().y, bBox.size().z/2);//, 1, 1, 1 );
                    var wireMaterial3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x8888ff,  opacity: 0.01,transparent: true} );
                    var wall = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wireMaterial2);
                    wall.position.copy(voxel.position);
                    wall.position.x = wall.position.x+bBox.size().x/4;
                    wall.position.z = wall.position.z+bBox.size().z/4;
                    MovingCube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry, wireMaterial2 );
                     MovingCube.position.copy(voxel.position);


                    var wall2 = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wireMaterial2);
                    wall2.position.copy(voxel.position);
                    wall2.position.x = wall2.position.x-bBox.size().x/4;
                    wall2.position.z = wall2.position.z+bBox.size().z/4;

                    var wall4 = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wireMaterial2);
                    wall4.position.copy(voxel.position);
                    wall4.position.x = wall4.position.x-bBox.size().x/4;
                    wall4.position.z = wall4.position.z-bBox.size().z/4;

                    var wall3 = new THREE.Mesh(wallGeometry, wireMaterial2);
                    wall3.position.copy(voxel.position);
                    wall3.position.x = wall3.position.x+bBox.size().x/4;
                    wall3.position.z = wall3.position.z-bBox.size().z/4;

                     //debugger;
                 if (created) {
                    // dae.traverse(function(child) {
                        // if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                             meshs.push(voxel);
                        // }
                     //});

                     var originPoint = rollOverMesh.position.clone();
                    for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < rollOverMesh.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++)
                    {       
                        var localVertex = rollOverMesh.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
                        var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4( rollOverMesh.matrix );
                        var directionVector = globalVertex.sub( rollOverMesh.position );
                        //debugger;
                        var ray2 = new THREE.Raycaster( originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize() );

                        var collisionResults = ray2.intersectObjects( collidableMeshList );

                        if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length() ) 
                            {

                            console.log(" Hit ");   
                            notHit = false;                             
                            }   


                    }


                 }  
                 if(notHit){

                    scene.add( voxel );

                    objects.push( voxel );

                    //collidableMeshList.push(MovingCube);
                    //collidableMeshList2.push(wallGeometry);
                    collidableMeshList.push(wall);

                    collidableMeshList.push(wall2);

                    collidableMeshList.push(wall3);

                    collidableMeshList.push(wall4);

                    //sscene.add(MovingCube);

                    scene.add(wall);
                    scene.add(wall2);
                    scene.add(wall3);
                    scene.add(wall4);

                    }
                }

                render();
                //debugger;
            created=true;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Java3D which is a 3D Java API whereas you use the 3D Javascript API called "Three.js".

Comment: yes you are right am using three.js API